# Finding real world reference points on assessor's map

Tags: georeferencing, parcel

This is probably a very basic question, but I don't even know the right terms to use to start searching for what I need. I'm new to this, but I want to learn.

I have the following assessor's map, and I am trying to reference it to the real world so that I can approximately survey the boundaries of a particular lot on block 052. What reference point(s) can I use as starting point?

It seems like the blocks were originally divided into 25 ft by 125 ft lots, and the current parcels are legally described in reference to those lots.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet would be to use QGIS and the "Parcels" dataset available from the San Diego GIS Data Warehouse:

[SANGIS](https://rdw.sandag.org/Account/gisdtview?dir=Parcel)

You will need an account, but it is easy enough to set up. Took me 5mins.

Once you have downloaded the data, you can add the Zip file directly into QGIS  by dragging and dropping it.

All you need to do is then find your area of interest (easy enough using Google Earth and the QGIS Base maps).

Google Earth:

[image]

QGIS with Basemap:

[image]

Adding the parcels, you can see the common points between your diagram and the parcel dataset (Look at the meeting of the parcel boundaries in the middle).

You can add a Georeferencer Tool to QGIS via the Plugins menu -> Manage and Install Plugins (search for Georeferencer) and **Georeferencer GDAL** will popup.

Install and you will find the tool under the "Raster" menu.
select Georeferencer and a new window will pop-up. Add your raster  to this window and hit the play button. You will be asked a few questions - Just select an output SRS and file name, leave everything else for now. Hit ok.

Next add a point a new window will pop-up and you can select **Use map canvas**, then select the common point on the map. You can see below that red dots are added everytime you do this.

[image]

Repeat this process at least 3 more times and try to get a spread across the raster - try for each corner and maybe the middle. When you done, his the "Play" button again. You should see a "Successful" ribbon popup in the Georeferencing window.

You can then add the gereferenced image to QGIS.

[image]